# POST data not being received

Tags: mysql, php, iphone

I've got an iPhone App that is supposed to send POST data to my server to register the device in a MySQL database so we can send notifications etc... to it. It sends it's unique identifier, device name, token, and a few other small things like passwords and usernames as a POST request to our server. The problem is that sometimes the server doesn't receive the data. And by this I mean, its not just receiving blank values for the POST inputs but, its not receiving ANY post data at all. I am logging all POST inputs to my server into some log files and when the script that relies on the POST data from the device fails (detects no data) I notice that its because NO POST data was sent. Is this a problem on the server, like refusing data or something or does this have to be on the client's side? What could be causing this?

Answer (score 1):

This is likely a problem on the client side, though there's an easy way to test, by just sending POST data to your script from an html page you can easily create, and then you can rule out the server.

Answer (score 0):

I like to use this Free [http post tool](http://soft-net.net/SendHTTPTool.aspx) to test send post request and get the post response